# $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c|x-y|^{\alpha}$ uniformly continuous, while c>0 and $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\supset X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a function with the property that c>0 and $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1]$ exist such that for all $x,y\in X$ following holds:
$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c|x-y|^{\alpha}$.

Show under application of the $\varepsilon -\delta$-definition that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

If $\alpha$ could be 0 there wouldn't be anything to prove, but what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ then fix $\delta =\frac{\epsilon^{1/\alpha}}{c^{1/\alpha}}$. Then if
$$|x-y|<\delta$$
We have
$$
|f(y)-f(x)|\leq c|x-y|^\alpha<c\left(\frac{\epsilon^{1/\alpha}}{c^{1/\alpha}}\right)^\alpha=\epsilon
$$
So $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: oh, so if "you" give me some arbitarly small epsilon i can afterwards pick a delta dependant of your epsilon?

Comment: Exactly that's what one has to do. The fact that delta depends only on epsilon, but not on x implies the continuty is uniform.
Another comment is that for $\alpha =0$ the result does not hold!

Comment: i dont understand, wenn $\alpha$ would be 0, then |f(x)-f(y)| would be simply smaller(or eq) then a fixed c, so i could just say $\delta=c$ or not? or does continousness require that the difference is really small?

Comment: If we set \alpha=0. Then the condition will be $|f(x)-f(y)|<c$. Then for instance if I give you $\epsilon=c/2$ Then no matter what $\delta$ you pick you cannot prove $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon=c/2$.
To see an eample consider $c=1$, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $1$ otherwise. Then it's true that $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$ everywhere. but the function is not continuous anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\varepsilon>0$ and set $\delta=\left({\varepsilon\over c}\right)^{1\over\alpha}$.  So we have
$$
|x-y|<\delta\implies c|x-y|^{\alpha}<\varepsilon\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon
$$